# Elm language documentation inside Atom editor like in LightTable

Tags: atom-editor, elm, lighttable

Is it possible to get documentation for Elm language like in this [screencast](http://rundis.github.io/blog/2015/elm_light.html), which uses LightTable? Specifically:

- panel for language documenation

[image]

- documentation for single function

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [language-elm](https://atom.io/packages/language-elm) package? It uses the same elm-oracle back-end.

Comment: isn't elm-oracle used for autocomplete and not for documentation? "In order to get autocomplete working, please: npm install -g elm-oracle" https://atom.io/packages/language-elm. "Query for information about values in elm source files" https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-oracle

Comment: elm-oracle provides documentation too. [Here's an example of using elm-vim and `:ElmShowDocs`](http://content.screencast.com/users/chadgilbert/folders/Jing/media/f97eed3e-a77c-4059-98c2-48b5f399a9d0/2016-06-16_1347.png) to pull documentation from elm-oracle. The Atom package says nothing about it so perhaps doc-fetching is not yet implemented within Atom, but it works fine in other editors (Vim, Emacs, Lighttable).

Comment: language-elm is doing some docs as of this writing, but it's not as robust as what you've shown above. If you haven't already, please create an issue there with these great screenshots.

Comment: I've already submitted issue, without screenshots though https://github.com/edubkendo/atom-elm/issues/42